# Cant findAll if you are a sibling in Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some HTLML that I am trying to parse that is formatted with almost no class identifiers so I have very little to have BeautifulSoup to latch on. It looks sort of like this:

```
<h3>I am an important section of the list</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="commonStuff/newThing1">Important text in here</a></li>
    <li><a href="commonStuff/newThing2">Differentmportant text in here</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
<h3>I am another section of the list but I am not important</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="I look like I could be important">Cool looking info in here></li>
    <li><a href="I look like I could be important">Cool looking info in here></li>  
</ul>
```

I only care about the `a` elements in-between the `h3` tags I care about. Naturally the way I am currently doing this is:

```
sections = part.select('h3')
        for section in sections:
            if "I am an important section of the list" in section:
```

The problem is I dont know what to do afterward because at that point I am looking for the stuff **after** the header tag. The only way I have seen to do that is with some sort of get children function. So I am doing this:

```
for body in section.next_siblings:
```

There are two things bad about this

- There should only ever be one sibiling after it. I dont really understadn in what case there would be multiple
- I cant do `for links in body.find_all("a"):` because the siblings aren't the same as the original html soup I was parsing earlier

How would you suggest getting to the href link as well as the text inside the `<a>` tag only if it is directly under a `<h3>` tag I care about?

The trouble here seems to be that I want the content directly after the `<h3>` tag. It would be nice if I could somehow split the document by the content between such tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next_siblings` exists without plural, to find the first next sibling :

```
res = []
sections = part.find_all('h3', 
                         string=lambda s:'I am an important section of the list' in s)
for section in sections:
    for item in section.next_sibling.next_sibling.find_all('a'):
        res.append(item.get('href'))

print(res)

>>>['commonStuff/newThing1', 'commonStuff/newThing2']
```

---

**Explanations about `next_sibling`:**

If your html source contains no linebreak after `<h3>`, you'd need only one `next_sibling`. BeautifulSoup interprets it as a [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring).

In this first example, we get the linebreak :

```
html = """
<h3>I am an important section of the list</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="commonStuff/newThing1">Important text in here</a></li>
    <li><a href="commonStuff/newThing2">Differentmportant text in here</a></li>
</ul>
 """
soup = soup(html, 'html.parser')

sections = soup.find_all('h3')
for section in sections:
    print('next sibling : ', section.next_sibling)
    print(type(section.next_sibling))
```

result :

```
next sibling :  

<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
```

---

In this one, without linebreak after `<h3>`, we obtain directly the tag we are searching :

```
html = """
<h3>I am an important section of the list</h3><ul>
    <li><a href="commonStuff/newThing1">Important text in here</a></li>
    <li><a href="commonStuff/newThing2">Differentmportant text in here</a></li>
</ul>
 """
soup = soup(html, 'html.parser')

sections = soup.find_all('h3')
for section in sections:
    print('next sibling : ', section.next_sibling)
    print(type(section.next_sibling))
```

result :

```
next sibling :  <ul>
<li><a href="commonStuff/newThing1">Important text in here</a></li>
<li><a href="commonStuff/newThing2">Differentmportant text in here</a></li>
</ul>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

Comment: Perfect! Item.text gets me the stuff between the brackets how would I get to the href link?

Comment: Could you explain why find_all() is only defined if you call next_sibling twice? For some reason it is not defined if you do it once. I think this has something to do with your 'plural' term

Comment: It's related to the html source, and the linebreaks, i added some examples